# Generalizations of the Tietze extension theorem (and Lusin's theorem)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I am reasking a year-old [math.stackexchange.com question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155138/generalizations-for-tietzes-extension-theorem) asked by someone else.

(For my needs every space $X$ and $Y$ will be Polish---that is a completely separably metrizable space.)

[The Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) says that if $X$ is a Polish space (even a normal space) and $Y=\mathbb{R}^n$, then a continuous function $f:C \rightarrow Y$ on a closed set $C \subseteq X$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:X \rightarrow Y$.

It seems important to the theorem in general that $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$, however there are some examples of pairs $X,Y$ where the theorem also holds.  For example, it is true if $X, Y \in \{2^\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\}$.  (Although, other pairs like $X=\mathbb{R}, Y = 2^\mathbb{N}$ do not hold.)

> Is there a characterization of the pairs $X,Y$ (or $X,Y,C$) for which the Tietze extension theorem holds?
>
> If not, what extensions are known, especially those that include my $2^\mathbb{N}$ example above?

---

One motivation for asking this question is [Lusin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem):
If $(X,\mathcal{B},P)$ is a Borel probability measure on a Polish space $X$ (even a Radon measure on a finite measure space) and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a measurable map (again $Y$ is Polish, or even second countable), then for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $C$ of measure $1-\varepsilon$ such that $f$ is continuous on $C$.

If $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can apply the Tietze extension theorem to find some continuous $g:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $g = f$ on $C$.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) currently (12 July 2013) has a **false statement** that for any locally compact $X$ we can find such a continuous $g:X \rightarrow Y$.  For a counterexample, take $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=2^\mathbb{N}$ and $f$ to be the bit representation of the reals.

I am interested in which cases this stronger version of Lusin's thoerem (with the continuous $g:X \rightarrow Y$) holds.

Comment: Tietze's extension theorem also holds for mappings into locally convex spaces, see http://msp.org/pjm/1951/1-3/pjm-v1-n3-p04-p.pdf .

Comment: The spaces $Y$ where Tietze's extension theorem holds are called absolute retracts.

Comment: (Tietze is not characteristic, so to speak).

Comment: Urysohn. Borsuk. A lot.

Comment: Also absolute neighborhood retracts.

Comment: E.g. $\dim X\le n,\ Y=S^n$ (also $Y=\mathbb R^{n+1}\backslash \{0\}$).

Comment: @Wlodzimierz Holsztynski. Can you please comment using complete sentences? Not using complete sentences is very annoying.

Comment: I wish there would be a little of tolerance.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz Holsztynski, I agree with Joseph Van Name,  I imagine your comments are insightful.  However, as they are, I can't understand them.  I would value (and upvote) an answer from you that elaborates on your comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a nice characterization of the spaces $X$ where the Tietze extension theorem holds for all complete separable metric spaces $Y$. We say that a Hausdorff space $X$ is ultranormal if whenever $R,S$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$, then there is some clopen set $C$ with $R\subseteq C$ and $S\subseteq C^{c}$. A Hausdorff space $X$ is ultraparacompact if every open cover of $X$ is refinable by a partition of $X$ into clopen sets. Every ultraparacompact space is ultranormal, every ultranormal space is zero-dimensional, and every ultranormal metric space is ultraparacompact. Furthermore, a space is ultraparacompact if and only if it is paracompact and ultranormal. Every zero-dimensional separable metric space is ultraparacompact and hence ultranormal. Therefore for separable metric spaces, the notions of ultranormality, ultraparacompactness, and zero-dimensionality coincide. See [my paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6086v1.pdf) for more information on ultranormality and ultraparacompactness. This paper is an expanded version of a long answer I gave to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37392/totally-disconnected-and-zero-dimensional-spaces/134184#134184) here on MO.

$\mathbf{Theorem}$ (Ellis)

1. Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then $X$ is ultranormal if and only if whenever $C\subseteq X$ is a closed subspace, $Y$ is a complete separable metric space, $C\subseteq X$ is a closed subspace, then every map from $C$ to $Y$ can be extended to a map from $X$ to $Y$.
2. Let $X$ be an ultraparacompact space and let $C$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Let $Y$ be a complete metric space. Then every continuous map from $C$ to $Y$ can be extended to a map from $X$ to $Y$.///

For a proof of the above result, see the paper [Extending Continuous Functions on Zero-Dimensional Spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01350686) by Robert Ellis.

Comment: This is a nice answer.  Although, I am still holding out hope for something more general---say where $X$ is not zero-dimensional and $Y$ is not an absolute retract.

Comment: The problem whether a map $f:C\rightarrow Y$ extends to a map $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is undecidable in even the simplest cases. If $X=I\times I$ and $C=\partial X$ (here we take the boundary of $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) and $\ell:I\rightarrow Y$ is a loop with basepoint $r$, then let $f(x,0)=\ell(x)$ and $f(x,y)=r$ otherwise. The extensions of $f$ are the homotopies of $\ell$ to a point. However, it is well known that the word problem in group theory can be formulated in terms of whether a loop is equivalent to the identity in the fundamental group, and the word problem is undecidable.

Comment: I would therefore be a bit surprised if there is a nice general characterization of when we can extend a map from a subset to the whole space.

Answer (score 6):

A compact space $Y$ is called an *absolute extensor in dimension $0$* abbreviated $AE(0)$ if the pair $X,Y$ satisfies Tietze extension theorem for every compact zero-dimensional $X$. Any compact (retract of a) topological group is $AE(0)$ (Schepin/Uspenski). In particular $2^\mathbb{N}$ is $AE(0)$. In fact, Schepin proved that the only zero-dimensional $AE(0)$ space with character $\kappa$ at every point is $2^\kappa$.