# Classify spaces that make extension theorems hold

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Recall a Polish space is a completely metrizable separable space.

- Say a Polish space $Y$ is a *terminal space* if for any Polish space $X$ and any closed $C \subseteq X$, one can extend a continuous map $f: C \rightarrow Y$ to a continuous map $g : X \rightarrow Y$.  (Examples of terminal spaces include $\mathbb{R}^n$, $C([0,1])$, $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$.  In the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case this is the Tietze extension theorem.)
- Say a Polish space $X$ is an *initial space* if for any Polish space (completely metrizable separable space) $Y$ and any closed $C \subseteq X$, one can extend a continuous map $f: C \rightarrow Y$ to a continuous map $g : X \rightarrow Y$.  (Examples of initial spaces include $\mathbb{N}$, $2^\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. The proofs are easy.  Also, initial spaces $X$ are "totally path disconnected" in that each continuous $h:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ is constant.)

> > **1. Do these classes of spaces have names?  (I made up the names "initial" and "terminal".)**
> >
> > **2. Have they been previously studied?**
> >
> > **3. Is there a nice classification of each type of space?**

It is possible that questions have obvious answers and I just don't know enough topology to answer them, but if they do, then I assume this has already been recorded somewhere.

This is a simplified version of a [previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136554/generalizations-of-the-tietze-extension-theorem-and-lusins-theorem) I was told is intractable.  I am interested in this result due to its connections to uniform computation (in a sense, extending truth-table reducibility to other spaces).

**Update 1:**
Kjos-Hanssen pointed out in the comments that my terminal spaces are similar to absolute retracts.  In trying to figure out his comment, I realized that being terminal is equivalent to being an absolute retract *for the class of Polish spaces*.

[Proof: Let $Y$ be an absolute retract (for the class of Polish spaces) and consider $C \xrightarrow{f}{} Y \xrightarrow{i}{} C[0,1]  \xrightarrow{r}{} Y$ where $f$ is a continuous map, $i$ is an isometric embedding (see Theorem 3.6 [here](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep90.ps)), and $r$ is the continuous map that one gets from $Y$ being an absolute retract.  Namely, $r(i(y))=y$ and so $r \circ i \circ f = f$.  Then since $C[0,1]$ is terminal, one has an extension $g$ of $i \circ f$ to the domain $X \supseteq C$.  Then $r \circ g$ is an extension of $f$.  Hence $Y$ is terminal.

Now, let $Y$ be terminal and consider some Polish space $X$ containing $Y$ as a closed subspace.  Since $Y$ is terminal, the continuous identity map can be extended to a continuous map $X \mapsto Y$.  Therefore, $Y$ is an absolute retract for the class of Polish spaces.]

**Update 2:**
(This is embarrassing...) I realize that Joseph Van Name already classified the initial spaces as the zero-dimensional Polish spaces in his answer to my previous [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136554/generalizations-of-the-tietze-extension-theorem-and-lusins-theorem?lq=1).  I should have looked that question (from a year and a half ago) over more closely before asking this one.  I had only remembered he told me that the more general question about which pairs $(X,Y)$ have this extension property is undecidable.  I forgot he answered the special cases I just asked about here.

Comment: Are you in particular asking whether terminal implies absolute retract?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen : I didn't know about absolute retract spaces.  I guess your comment led me to realize that being terminal is the same as being an absolute retract for the class of Polish spaces.  I am not sure if this is the exact same as an absolute retract space (which is with respect to the class of metric spaces).  Also, I don't know if an AR Polish space has a better characterization or not.