# The set of continuous bounded functions $f:X\to Y$ is dense in $L^p(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are Polish

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

It is well known that the set of real-valued continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^p(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a Radon measure (see e.g. [Folland, Proposition 7.9])  Clearly, the set of continuous bounded functions includes those compactly supported continuous functions, and when the spaces we are considering are Polish (i.e., a complete and separable metric space) and $\mu$ is a probability measure, the situation simplifies, and we get the following.

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a Polish space with a Borel probability measure $\mu$. $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})=\{f:X\to \mathbb{R}|f\textrm{ is continuous and bounded}\}$ is dense in $L^p(X,\mathbb{R})$, the set of real-valued $L^p$ functions with respect to $\mu$.

I want to generalize this theorem when the target space $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by more general space. I want to replace $\mathbb{R}$ with another Polish space $Y$, but if there is any less/more general formulation, I would like to know about it. So my question is the following:

**Question**: Let $X$ be a Polish space with a Borel probability measure $\mu$, and let $Y$ be another Polish space. Is $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})=\{f:X\to Y|f\textrm{ is continuous and bounded}\}$ dense in $L^p(X,Y)$?

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comment, this is false, but I am also interested in a case when $Y$ has a stronger condition (such as being connected).

**Definitions:**
I denote the metrics on $X, Y$ by $d_X, d_Y$, respectively.

- $f:X\to Y$ is said to be bounded if $f(X)$ is a bounded set in $Y$ i.e. there exists $c>0$ s.t. for any $x,x'\in X$, $d_Y(f(x),f(x'))<c$.
- $L^p(X,Y)$ is the set of Borel-measurable functions $f:X\to Y$ such that $\int_{\Omega}d^p_Y(f(x),y_0)d\mu < \infty$ for some $y_0\in Y$. The separability of $Y$ ensures that $X\ni x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))\in Y\times Y$ is Borel measurable, so the integral of $d^p_Y(f(x),g(x))$ is well defined, and the metric on $L^p(X,Y)$ is defined by $d_{L^p}(f,g)=(\int_{X}d^p_Y(f(x),g(x))d\mu)^{1/p}$. I referred to [this paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cag/1993/0001/0004/CAG-1993-0001-0004-a004.pdf) for the definition.

**My Work**: I would like to try a similar approach as the real case (see [this post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226049/continuous-functions-on-0-1-is-dense-in-lp0-1-for-1-leq-p-infty)),  According to *Geometric Measure Theory* by Federer, Lusin's theorem can be generalized to metric valued functions (Theorem 2.3.5). So, I don't think that part is an issue. The problem arises with Tietze's extension theorem, as this one does not hold in our general setting (The identity on $\mathbb{S}^1$ cannot be extended continuously to a $\mathbb{S}^1$-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^2$). So, we must settle for a less general setting or figure out a new approach. As for the less general setting, I found [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136554/generalizations-of-the-tietze-extension-theorem-and-lusins-theorem?rq=1) regarding the generalization of Tieze, but this does not seem very general to me. At the very least, I would like to prove (or disprove) the case $Y=\mathbb{S}^1$, but I am stuck here.

Comment: What happened when $X$ is connected and $Y$ discrete ?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Ah, so any continuous function is a constant map in that case, so it won't be true. I guess I would need a stronger assumption like connectivity on $Y$.